# Properly handle WebRequests

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I have a dynamic page with a .JSON file, and I'm using my C# program to access it every x number of seconds, to determine if something has been changed or not. Everything works flawlessly as long as I have Internet connection, if for whatever reason I lose it, then my program crashes as the ex.Response is a null. I was wondering if there's a better way of handling the following code:

```
void Function(){
while(true){
 jList = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<jsonList>(GET(jsonUrl)); 
//SOME THINGS I DO with the data above here

Thread.Sleep(5000);
}}



     string GET(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            if (ex.Response != null) { 
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // log errorText
            }
        }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Perhaps I should ping it first, and see if I get a reply, and only then Perform the WebRequest function?

EDIT:

After adding this

```
  public bool getResponse(string URL)
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                string HTMLSource = wc.DownloadString(URL);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

And use it as

```
void Function(){
while(true){
        if (!getResponse(jsonUrl))
                {
                    return;
                }
 jList = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<jsonList>(GET(jsonUrl)); 
//SOME THINGS I DO with the data above here

Thread.Sleep(5000);
}}
```

My C# application waits a bit, and then exits normally. Why?

The program '[10476] Kiosk2.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: ping is not guaranteeed its ICMP, it has a low priority in the world, secondly, even if it did ping, it doesnt guarantee a web response.. The answer is to handle your error better - you obviously arent checking somewhere that your data is there or your program wouldnt crash

Comment: Ideally I think that it should check if the page is available before trying to read the data from it. Somewhere in the void Function() in the end-less loop. I tried this but still not there
        bool RemoteWebOnline(string url)
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response;
            try
            {
                response = request.GetResponse();
                Console.WriteLine("Web response: "+response);
                return true;
            } catch
            {
               return false;
            }
     }

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well this seems to work fine for me.

```
  public void Update() //CALLED IT void FUNCTION earlier
        {

            while (true)
            {
                while (getResponse(jsonUrl))
                {


                    jList = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<jsonList>(GET(jsonUrl));

 //I DO SOME STUFF HERE
 //INTERESTING STUFF


                    Thread.Sleep(5000);

                }

            }


        }
```

And seconds function:

```
public bool getResponse(string URL)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string HTMLSource = wc.DownloadString(URL);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```